# Print repeating values from a given column in a table as many times as they occur. SQL

Tags: sql, count, where-clause, window-functions

Ok so we know we can check if a column has duplicate values by using using **Group By** along with **Having** keyword and an aggregate function like `Count()`.

What if I want to do is to print those duplicate values, not once but as many times as they are present in the table?

So if a column contains: `1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,8.`
I want my query to return: `2,2,2,5,5,8,8,8.`

Group by/distinct will only show 2, 5, 8. How can I get what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please tag only the one database you are running.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution. Not limited to a specific database.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute a window count in a subquery, then use it to filter the resultset:

```
select val
from (select val, count(*) over(partition by val) cnt from mytable) t
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: How about find ones which occur only once and then MINUS them from the table. Only repeating values will be left.

Comment: The above query gives you only values that occur more than once, which is how I understood your question. What do you mean by *substracting* from the table?

Comment: You understood it fine. There is a MINUS keyword, Q1 MINUS Q2 means the resulting query will have all elements from Q2 except the ones in Q1.

Comment: @MuhammadFaraz: no need for that. Just us the above query. On the other hand if you want values that occur only once, then change the `where` clause to `where cnt = 1`.